# Generate descriptive statistics for different variable types in R

Tags: r, apply

I know there are a plethora of packages/functions such as (janitor) "tabyl" & "pastec" to get the descriptive values of variables, but I don't know how to apply them over only certain columns.

For example

```
library(pastec)
stat.desc(iris)
```

will return the mean/sd etc., for all the variable, but I want to apply it **only to the numeric** variables. I don't want to subset, because my data set has over 20 columns and the numeric columns are interspersed in varying orders.

Something else I tried is:

```
library(janitor) 
lapply(iris,tabyl)
```

Which is great, except that I don't want tabyl applied over all the columns (because columns with 14,000 ID's makes for an ugly output) & my ultimate aim is to throw this into a neat looking excel file.

Any idea's for how I can apply these cool functions for 'numeric' types and 'character'/'factor' types separately? Or to specific columns specified in a vector?

Comment: Subset the data you `lapply` to. Something like `nums = sapply(iris, is.numeric); lapply(iris[nums], tabyl)`. Or, write yourself a wrapper function that looks at the column type and picks the right function to use.

Comment: Package `DescTools` has a `Desc` function that produces different summary stats for different variable types. If you have Microsoft Word, it will pass tables and plots to an open Word document.

Answer (score 1):

{dplyr} package has some neat ways to select `numeric`, `character` variables etc.

For example:

```
library(pastecs)
library(dplyr)

stat.desc(select_if(iris, is.numeric))
```

Good luck!